# Tidyup PHP if else function

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

i'm really struggling (as a PHP newbie) to tidy up this code and get it to work (statements within statements in wordpress). Hopefully you should be able to understand what i'm trying to do from the code i have below:

Thanks for your help ...

```
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying Author archive pages
*
* @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
* @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
*/

get_header(); 

//phpinfo();
?>

<div class="slider non-home">
<div class="homebanner">
<div class="home royalSlider">
<div class="rsImg"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="main" style="margin-top:20px;">
<div class="hundred">
<div class="page-header">
<?php $userID = intval($author);
if(isset($_GET['author_name'])) :
$curauth = get_userdatabylogin($author_name);
else :
$curauth = get_userdata(intval($author));
endif; ?>
<ul class="profile-list">
<?php
if ($curauth->_mgm_user_status; > 'expired') {
echo "
<li><strong>Status:</strong> <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_user_status; ?></li>
<li><strong>Member No.:</strong> <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_membership_id; ?></li>
<li><strong>Title:</strong> <?php echo $curauth->_mgm_cf_title; ?></li>
<li><strong>First Name:</strong> <?php echo $curauth->first_name; ?></li>
<li><strong>Surname:</strong> <?php echo $curauth->last_name; ?></li>
</ul>

";
} else {
echo "Sorry, this user has expired";
}
?>
</div>
<div class="col13">
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("page_sidebar") ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It all echos and produces data on the front end but i just cant get it all to only show if the $curauth->_mgm_user_status bit equals 'expired'.

Comment: You are using `<?php` inside `<?php`

Comment: Besides that, are there any issues or would the below solutions help me? Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($curauth->_mgm_user_status != 'expired')
   {
     echo "<li><strong>Status:</strong>".$curauth->_mgm_user_status."</li>
    <li><strong>Member No.:</strong> ". $curauth->_mgm_cf_membership_id."</li>
    <li><strong>Title:</strong> ". $curauth->_mgm_cf_title."</li>
    <li><strong>First Name:</strong> ". $curauth->first_name."</li>
    <li><strong>Surname:</strong> ". $curauth->last_name."</li>
   </ul>";
    } 
else 
    {
     echo "Sorry, this user has expired";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. UNfortunately, this still displayed the results, even when the user's status was 'expired'.

Comment: I've added some code beforehand that is in my author.php file - could this be causing problems with your code?

Comment: the conditional statement is very simple and obvious , please show me the full code ..

Comment: I've added the full page - thank you

Comment: please add `var_dump($curauth);` before the conditional statement for debugging and post the result

Comment: NULL - Sorry and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
if ($curauth->_mgm_user_status == 'Active')
```

Thanks Kamel!